# What is a probability that two StackOverflow questions share a tag?

Tags: probability

Stack Overflow has 13m questions and ca. 50k tags of various frequency. We also know that every Stack Overflow question is tagged with at least one and at most five tags.

Assume that the tags are chosen randomly, i.e., based on the frequency only rather than on personal preferences of the askers, and cannot be edited.

Is there a way to estimate the probability that two questions share a tag?

Comment: @Ramanujan I guess that the answer is the sum of squares of probabilities that the individual tag has been chosen (the sum over all tags). I would have known how to solve this if I had a small number of tags---this would be the classical problem with choosing balls from an urn, right? However, with 50K tags each one having different probability this seems to be impossible.